# put vue variable with mounted on section('title')

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

i have problem with showing vue variable on blade template

my layouts/master.blade.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@yield('title') | My company</title>
.....
```

news.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

<div id="pagetitle">
@section('title', @{{pagetitle}} )
</div>

@section('content')
....
@endsection
```

resources/js/news.js

```
new Vue({

    el: '#pagetitle',

    data: {
        pagetitle:'',
    },

    mounted() {
        this.fetchArticlesPage();
    },

    methods: {
        fetchArticlesPage(page_url) {
            page_url = '/api/articles/news';
            fetch(page_url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => this.pagetitle = res.page_title)
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        },

    }
});
```

and this response data from controller with jsonResource

```
{
 "links": {
    "first": "http://localhost:8000/api/articles/news?page=1",
    "last": "http://localhost:8000/api/articles/news?page=1",
    "prev": null,
    "next": null
  },
  "meta": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "path": "http://localhost:8000/api/articles/news",
    "per_page": 3,
    "to": 3,
    "total": 3
  },
  "page_title": "News"
}
```

i got syntax error unexpected {

if i put on @section('content') like this

```
@section('content')
   <div id="pagetitle">
     @{{pagetitle}}
   </div>
@stop
```

it' fine and will show the data which is "News",
please help, am new in vue and laravel programing

Comment: We can't help you without knowing what `fetch(page_url)` returns. Could you place that JSON inside a variable in the above script and replace `fetch(page_url)` with it so we can see what's actually going on after the result is fetched?

Comment: ok, i will edit my post

Answer (score 0):

The Blade template directives are processed in the server and a response sent to the client.

After this, Vue template directives are processed in the browser.

On that account, the later example with the escaped *Vue mustache* works as expected as the block below is sent to the browser as a part of the overall response content.

```
   <div id="pagetitle">
     {{pagetitle}}
   </div>
```

The Vue program running in the browser then runs, and interpolates variables in this template.

For the former example,

```
@section('title', @{{pagetitle}})
```

will result in an error in the server when it tries to compile the section as the second parameter is not given as a string.

This error can be corrected by quoting the escaped *Vue mustache*.

```
@section('title', '@{{pagetitle}}')
```

**EDIT**: `{{pagetitle}}` *is not compiled is in document head*

The Vue instance that is created is mounted on an element contained in the body. For this reason, compilation happens only on the document tree of the element that the Vue instance is mounted on.

I suggest to create a separate Vue instance to manage the head of the document. e.g.

```
const helmet = new Vue({
    el: 'head',
    data: {
        pagetitle:'',
    },

    mounted() {
        this.fetchArticlesPage();
    },

    methods: {
        fetchArticlesPage(page_url) {
            page_url = '/api/articles/news';
            fetch(page_url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => this.pagetitle = res.page_title)
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        },

    }
})
```

Comment: thank you for helping me out bro, but that's not solve my problem, i try and result is {{pagetitle}} | My company on my browser

Comment: No worries. See update on the reason that {{pagetitle}} isn't compiled in the head

Answer (score 0):

u can try this

@section('title', @pagetitle)